# How to compile assets active admin demands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

The problem is when my rails project is deployed, it can't find these assets when on admin page:

> active_admin.self-f64966142a2c9e51b2886966eb553d7f410652b962c208bb464dd60c738c42d5.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery3.self-06c43429d1047ce3f355da574d8a9750209971b8b1b8f264f91f5518c5fcc060.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   version.self-c8e3d1203da26ea7efdf83c1eabb3f0ba55cb68e463f5ccf0d77bd15ce6a8e61.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   keycode.self-ad63cd20acf49dd333bbbc537454d7d475bd610eb5b88de0dca009f0c3d314b1.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   datepicker.self-2af0dec09da99d687c31fc224e940687a4eb3694e7b38b0871bba475cad86120.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   widget.self-fca20bcec06d192f97cffa6e734e24360e227237b8ae7d7e7e60754df7d5444f.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   controlgroup.self-0b7409f97114a33de116bd5429e9df199cbdea3f276d8bd725c4c2c60f244711.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   checkboxradio.self-0b7409f97114a33de116bd5429e9df199cbdea3f276d8bd725c4c2c60f244711.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   button.self-659b51f6fb5303f90ed8cf551509063770a50168a15795ba834b08f8bf2e0ce0.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   ie.self-163eb039dcb1e0c3471b7d91386eabb8753da6906e84824c019f9ff56bdb83a6.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   mouse.self-f0790a202dcf54fab051e71b042335d5346f9cceb0f645223c1dab93f349a04b.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   data.self-2067c82e6fe39a9cba5623206a5dc28d5c60d26b95cd100855b78cacf72865b8.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   plugin.self-d8f576c8e073ca51f095505f47bd09d306b875404cd90afcbb6338287cfb0247.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   safe-active-element.self-a1f1a1a7dae3269ce03f6fffb2dcc9b4a7490f5d546c65d54417bec3be24b668.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   safe-blur.self-2cc24c46132d51c7724f6371154241b0a81c9bae5d5681d8f62b01ce46236726.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   scroll-parent.self-38e26a71a450a29fb63425e8f589a7046862f927eb0a1dbf6a6c44da05196d2e.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   draggable.self-42c3eda0b49f105628cea7580fe38c7ed77467cee384bb2c4e095a2bd0a172e6.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   disable-selection.self-5675f71f2fbbc6857ea700ba843af748b50dbc0150cc87932a7d05ec016bb659.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   resizable.self-1a46c2f5b876918e02bf979080e56f57846590cd880721bca5058e84f7f60bae.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   focusable.self-426e99e67d1f1bd4cb444fd878ee63a6de1f5d1d61451e43022c86214b9eec64.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   position.self-1b49c8c521e67a4a88bfdad6b4d944d33686d25009a0e40a1e170acdd7b6962a.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   tabbable.self-f3f62ceed772d3a325cebd6a03221f8a8cb02c6150f4feba738c6525a2953690.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   unique-id.self-66e85ac85cd0b6b8b1bb89369fc65f608f716869dc0930862a8d421a57a9580a.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   dialog.self-2bd687f9580c0be4213c50b4bb1211c28ceedb045eba954e63d40bfbb4d1affd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   sortable.self-6e5e1f07a29b5a89ec1d359363d2800904e3ae548a38ab2f8eded36746d1adbe.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   escape-selector.self-43e4d61501e4ffb1ecba387affbae1eb3e1c863ab0b0e71897851cddd246e50e.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   tabs.self-b7f60535e992224ca66c3f11dc943eba9ef42a9605241e27b9dba24c7efb287e.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   base.self-ab2cb3098b53fe7d229937d768d701e8f4013f2a5aea7988d8f2149fa40426db.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   batch_actions.self-38f91c8a2e79d0d334f22e68440137ecad0a081f21e35bf9532de1e409f78e8a.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   checkbox-toggler.self-f3ac78175da0b7357ada35c7b7db4cd119ac305ab118a7effb24b1c5da629e07.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   dropdown-menu.self-5794b6ca26364ce522cb47a8ef050870fda0b886cfeef69ec27ef116900f1984.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   flash.self-8f05a5d9328ea28fca100b057787fbfb567986513c5f1735ea48fad8f9571c10.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   has_many.self-ece319debdc01ca5096ae8ac6c130ffc0decab382543b4b94e18591375d3d3bb.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   modal_dialog.self-5dfc6e87bae26cd4a021eb86951d3691ed07e6d2bf242a8eb65dc6965e12096c.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   per_page.self-ac2a7829e00b21d672b908a9a64b42aef7632ff1dac9a90dda0e779706c71256.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   table-checkbox-toggler.self-411adb7e5ac7ce5602bfedc685bb1253aa41b0f687599f11312f15805f9856f0.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery-ui.self-f96f2ec2a32c4bc4da4292cc74bddeca0bb223d81a421c98c4d613632860945e.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery.self-da8dafbbe883092bcae73f35a8caf4ae6170fe7d8130ae7039a233f9b509c757.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   batch_actions.self-f693d7e31a910829186af20c64f91da55574e3385b12465c151da4d63f7d9883.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   datepicker.self-305bbf9fc8b1de2fd07ea201cef994db1e32c3cc29b711f9f5fa13ea70681444.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   filters.self-a0ee45912355fd1c2122b7c9f94e2fcda6b78cd20723f85cd26d10016b060128.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   tabs.self-5bccad3e0e615bd96bf323490a71829beec067511af628e9808993bb6beeb3a5.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   active_admin.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   print.self-ae36e3283f23f7975609f7096668f7c63b5df69478c7b56d511dbdd316aa15b4.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   base.self-ab2cb3098b53fe7d229937d768d701e8f4013f2a5aea7988d8f2149fa40426db.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   batch_actions.self-38f91c8a2e79d0d334f22e68440137ecad0a081f21e35bf9532de1e409f78e8a.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   checkbox-toggler.self-f3ac78175da0b7357ada35c7b7db4cd119ac305ab118a7effb24b1c5da629e07.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   dropdown-menu.self-5794b6ca26364ce522cb47a8ef050870fda0b886cfeef69ec27ef116900f1984.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   flash.self-8f05a5d9328ea28fca100b057787fbfb567986513c5f1735ea48fad8f9571c10.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   has_many.self-ece319debdc01ca5096ae8ac6c130ffc0decab382543b4b94e18591375d3d3bb.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   modal_dialog.self-5dfc6e87bae26cd4a021eb86951d3691ed07e6d2bf242a8eb65dc6965e12096c.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   per_page.self-ac2a7829e00b21d672b908a9a64b42aef7632ff1dac9a90dda0e779706c71256.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   table-checkbox-toggler.self-411adb7e5ac7ce5602bfedc685bb1253aa41b0f687599f11312f15805f9856f0.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery-ui.self-f96f2ec2a32c4bc4da4292cc74bddeca0bb223d81a421c98c4d613632860945e.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   jquery.self-da8dafbbe883092bcae73f35a8caf4ae6170fe7d8130ae7039a233f9b509c757.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   batch_actions.self-f693d7e31a910829186af20c64f91da55574e3385b12465c151da4d63f7d9883.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   datepicker.self-305bbf9fc8b1de2fd07ea201cef994db1e32c3cc29b711f9f5fa13ea70681444.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   filters.self-a0ee45912355fd1c2122b7c9f94e2fcda6b78cd20723f85cd26d10016b060128.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   tabs.self-5bccad3e0e615bd96bf323490a71829beec067511af628e9808993bb6beeb3a5.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   active_admin.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   active_admin.self-f64966142a2c9e51b2886966eb553d7f410652b962c208bb464dd60c738c42d5.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   print.self-ae36e3283f23f7975609f7096668f7c63b5df69478c7b56d511dbdd316aa15b4.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I've already tried adding to production.rb and development.rb config.assets.precompile = true and config.assets.precompile += %w[active_admin.css active_admin.js], also I tried an advice to remove "require tree" from application.js, nothing helped. I've been searching for a week, how to compile these assets? :(
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please check in the `public/assets` folder to confirm if those files generated correctly. Also, check NginX `error.log`

Comment: @yeuem1vannam The problem is that those files are not generated at all

Comment: do you have them in your `application.js /css`?

Answer (score 0):

In my production environment, i had encounter similar issue. Even in my case  **self** was getting added in asset resource name. issue resolved after disabling following property

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

for info http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html